# Emailing navigator.useragent

Tags: php, javascript, html, user-agent

Is there a way I can allow a user to email me their user agent at a click of a button (when submitting a form)

So somehow pass the devices navigator.useragent to the php form to send it off, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='user-agent' value='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>' />
```

Comment: Why not just use the variable in the php file sending the email? No need to submit it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster that is what i want. I want to be able to add it into my normal form as opposed to making a completely new one, but if this is my only option then so be it.

Comment: If the way your code is setup is to just send you the form results, this is the best way to add the user agent to the form.

Answer (score 3):

The User agent is available in the [`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-indices) superglobal. Beware though, its value can **easily** be spoofed.

In JavaScript, the value is available in the [`navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/window.navigator.userAgent) string. However, since the value does already exists at the server's side, I recommend `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` instead.

Comment: yep thanks. This is to benefit users anyway so if they could 'spoof' the process I doubt they would. I've found many Android tablets thinking they are Macintosh PC's and iPads and if thats what you mean by spoofing then that's fine :)

Comment: @JohnVasiliou Then it's OK. Do not add the value in a hidden input field, as suggested by others, because the value is available at each request. If you add the value to a hidden input field, the chance of spoofing increases.

Comment: <input type='submit' name='user-agent' value='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>' /> < would that be better?

Comment: @JohnVasiliou I assume that your form submission is handled by your own server. In that case, directly use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` instead of `$_POST['user-agent']`. When the form submits to a location whch you can't control, your current approach is fine (although I'd use `hidden` instead of `submit`).

Comment: Changing the input type to 'submit' will cause it to break.  The input type needs to be 'hidden'. Spoofing is not something you should be considering, it is extremely easy no matter what and there is nothing you can do to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You can create input (hidden o just text) and assign navigator.useragent to its value from javascript.

Comment: how can i go about making this work then? I have a html form which uses php to validate and send the results to me. along with this form I'd like to include the devices user-agent. Any ideas?

Comment: Or you can just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. No need for a form.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use javascript to access this information.  You can create a hidden form input and set its value on load or on submit.

Comment: how can i go about making this work then? I have a html form which uses php to validate and send the results to me. along with this form I'd like to include the devices user-agent. Any ideas?

Comment: The simplest solution would be the solution proposed by @jchavannes.  This would require no javascript and prepopulates the field for you.  You can do whatever you want with it once it's submitted.

Comment: So if I have a current form which submits as usual the code that @jchavannes would require a completely new form a my current form ends with input type="submit" and this one is different.

Comment: Not if you add it to the existing form.  Additionally you could just add `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to the email from the page that processes the post data instead of adding a new form field.

Comment: <input type='hidden' name='user-agent' value='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>' /><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /> I used that and it works fine. Thank you all :) any chance of adding in the screen resolution too or is that asking too much? haha

Comment: PHP doesn't know anything about your resolution.  A new, hidden form field that gets populated by javascript (screen.width and screen.height).  I'd say ask a new question to get more in-depth answers though.

Comment: yep, I added this code:

<input type='hidden' name='user-agent' value='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>' /><input type='hidden' name='width' value='<?php echo $_GET['width']; ?>' /><input type='hidden' name='height' value='<?php echo $_GET['height']; ?>' /><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />

and results are blank for width and height. thank you for everything anyway :D